# How to stop a yarn resourcemanager

Tags: hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I am facing issues in stopping resource manager on yarn. How to stop a yarn `resourcemanager`?

`yarn resourcemanager` - this command should restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager stop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR stop resourcemanager
```